# Download traffic flow data and weather data

Tags: here-api, traffic, weather-api

I am looking to download the traffic flow data and the weather data having the conditions

- Particular date
- Particular location(zipcode or latitude/longitude or geolocations)

I have seen some examples in this link to collect data using quadkey, bounding box, and corridor. https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-quadkey

My questions are

1. How could I specify the date or range of dates?
2. How could I get the quadkey, bounding box, and corridor of location?
3. I need the data of the previous day, it's not like historical, do I need a subscription for that

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers inline:

1. By default, traffic tiles show real-time traffic, representing the traffic situation at the time of the request.
   However, it is also possible to request a traffic tile showing the typical traffic pattern for a specific time and day during the week. To get a traffic pattern tile, add a **&time** parameter to the request, specifying the date and time for which to display the traffic situation. Based on historic information, the tile displays a typical traffic situation for that date and time.

More information provided here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/traffic-tiles.html

The traffic flow is explained based on color code explained here:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic/dev_guide/topics/tiles.html

Green  = Free flow of traffic: 0 <= JAM_FACTOR < 4

Yellow = Sluggish flow of traffic: 4 <= JAM_FACTOR < 8

Red    = Slow flow of traffic: 8 <= JAM_FACTOR < 10

Black  = Traffic stopped flowing or road closed: JAM_FACTOR = 10

2. (I) a quadkey is a string containing a numeric value. The value is obtained by interleaving the bits of the row and column coordinates of a tile in the grid at the given zoom level, then converting the result to a base-4 number (the leading zeros are retained). The length of a quadkey string (the number of digits/characters) equals the zoom level of the tile.

For example:

```js
// Convert the column (x) and row (y) values
// to their binary (b) equivalents:
x = 3 -> 011b

y = 5 -> 101b

// Interleave the binary values (b), convert the
// combined result to a base-4 (q) number and
// finally convert that to a string:
quadkey = 100111b -> 213q -> "213"
```

Here is the Javascript example that calculates the quadkey:

```js
--- input ---
xTile: 35210  // Column
yTile: 21493  // Row
z: 16     // Zoom Level

--- JavaScript ---
function tileXYToQuadKey(xTile, yTile, z) {
  var quadKey = "";
  for (var i = z; i > 0; i--) {
    var digit = "0",
    mask = 1 << (i - 1);
    if ((xTile & mask) != 0) {
      digit++;
    }
    
    if ((yTile & mask) != 0) {
      digit = digit + 2; 
    }
    quadKey += digit;
  } // for i return quadKey; 

  return quadKey;
}
quadKey = tileXYToQuadKey(35210, 21493, 16);

--- output ---
quadKey = "1202102332221212"
```

(II) The query parameter bbox defines the latitudes and longitudes of the top left and bottom right corners of the bounding box. The optional query parameter response attributes requests that the response include additional information on the shape and the functional class of the roadway corresponding to the flow items.
The bbox can be obtained from the geocode & search API.

For example:
Request:

```
https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?q=5+Rue+Daunou%2C+75000+Paris%2C+France
```

The response will have the map view containing the co-ordinates:

```js
"mapView": {
        "west": 2.33073,
        "south": 48.86836,
        "east": 2.33347,
        "north": 48.87016
      },
```

The detail information is explained here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/endpoint-geocode-brief.html

(III) Corridor Entrypoint represents sets of places along a route area sorted by distance from starting point of the route.
This information is available in the old search API

https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/resource-browse-by-corridor.html

With the new GS7 API you can refer to this link:
https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics/implementing-route.html

3. As mentioned in point 1, the traffic map tile is available for a given time by adding the parameter **&time** parameter to the query.